# How to get public keys in a non blocking manner

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, jjwt

According to the documentation a signing key resolver can fetch a key dynamically: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#signing-key-resolver

The following code does call a kotlin suspending function which retrieves the public key in a non blocking way:

```
val parser =
            Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKeyResolver(object : SigningKeyResolverAdapter() {
                    override fun resolveSigningKey(header: JwsHeader<out JwsHeader<*>>, claims: Claims?): Key {
                        return runBlocking {
                            retrievePublicKey(header["kid"])
                        }
                    }
                }).build()
        val claims = parser.parseClaimsJws(jwtString).body
```

Here is the definition of the suspending function

```
suspend fun retrievePublicKey(key:String):PublicKey {
...
}
```

The problem is that this code needs to block the thread(`runBlocking`). Otherwise it can't work.

This challenge also exists for all other async frameworks (rxjava, listenablefuture, completablefuture, ...)

Comment: `build()` method returns a thread-safe `JwtParser`. I guess `resolveSigningKey()` method is invoked in background thread (you can check it adding `Thread.currentThread()` to the  logs), so the thread can be blocked.

Comment: i don't think so: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/72973f9b9ba72438d97834db2bd56e36d3c48592/impl/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/impl/DefaultJwtParser.java#L251
I think they leave threading to us.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `jwtk` library is mostly synchronous, so it is not possible to directly use `suspend` to avoid blocking.

Rather you should probably wrap the library so the `parse*` calls are done on the `IO` dispatcher which is designed to handle blocking IO.
In addition if you design your `retrievePublicKey` suspend function to rely on the caller to handle threading you could make it do the neccesary blocking IO in the same thread without consuming more resources.

```kotlin
val parser = /* create parser with runBlocking */
val claims = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // This will end up synchronously calling runBlocking, if the
    //  suspend function does not explicitly switch context it will do its work
    //  on the same thread.
    parser.parseClaimsJws(jwtString)
}.body
```